# Resubscribe to Observable in Android Fragment

Tags: android, fragment, rx-java, rx-android

New to RxJava/Android and wondering where to place a subscriber in a Fragment?

Something like the following code is now placed in the Fragment's `onCreate`. `onNext` would be called several times when new data has been received which is not wanted. It would reload the data received multiple times, it should be done only once. What is the correct way to handle this?

If I do unsubscribe, where and how to resubscribe to listen for new data when returning back (after navigating away to an Activity) to this fragment again?

```
   Some.replaySubject
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(new Observer<Status>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onNext(Status status) {

                            switch (status) {
                                case NotLoaded:
                                   ...
                                    break;
                                case Loading:
                                    showSpinner();
                                    break;
                                case Background_Loading:
                                  ...
                                    break;
                                case Complete:
                                   reloadData();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use take 1. The observable completes after first emission.

http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/take.html

> You can emit only the first n items emitted by an Observable and then
>   complete while ignoring the remainder, by modifying the Observable
>   with the Take operator.

```
Some.replaySubject
    .take(1)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new Observer<Status>() {
        @Override
        public void onNext(Status status) {

            switch (status) {
                case NotLoaded:
                    ...
                    break;
                case Loading:
                    showSpinner();
                    break;
                case Background_Loading:
                    ...
                    break;
                case Complete:
                    reloadData();
```

To resubscribe, put this rx chain in onStart? onResume? Somewhere the life cycle callbacks will reinitiate it. Dispose of it onDestroy.